Configuring Journey Entry for Records with Pre-assigned Campaigns in Salesforce
I'm using Salesforce data in a Journey and need records that already have the campaign assigned to enter the Journey. How should I configure the Journey entry source to achieve this? Currently, it's set to update and create records, but they only enter the Journey after activation and when they get the campaign ID assigned.


The acceptance rate of good answers provided to your questions is very low. Ensuring good questions are accepted by you, will encourage the community to provide answers to your new questions too.

If you still want to use the Salesforce data entry source for the journey.
You would need to create a new version and update the criteria where the Lead Campaign ID Is Not Null.
Note: The records are only injected into the journey if they are created or updated (in the Lead Campaign ID field) though.

I would leverage Synchronized Data Extensions to get all Lead records who are assigned with a campaign, then use this data extension result for a new journey.
Following here is an example SQL query to get the result. You may need alter it based on the name of your synchronized DE name and the BU you execute the query.
SELECT
Id,
Email,
HasOptedOutOfEmail,
FirstName,
LastName
FROM
ENT.Lead_Salesforce
WHERE
Campaign_Id__c != ''


unfortunately this won't work as I need to use the Salesforce data source so the email is sent out instantly where with the sync data will have to wait for it to refresh and run the query

@Duicug What is the criteria to inject these Leads into the journey? What about old records who already are assigned to a campaign?

is campaignID equal ""

@Duicug I have updated the answer

if I select the criteria where the Lead Campaign ID Is Not Null I will get all the records that have a campaignID populated into the Journey which is not my desired goal

You mentioned in your question that you need records that already have a campaign assigned to enter the Journey, isn't it? Also, it doesn't include old records since a record only can be injected into a journey when it is not qualified first then it is qualified later

sorry, I meant to say, that specific campaign not any campaign

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
